# Is there a SVN Maven?

Tags: maven-2, ant

Is there something for maven like http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html ? Something to automate your project updates without having to click update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Maven SCM Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/index.html) does support [Subversion](http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html). Check the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the possibility to run ant inside maven.
Ant is much more powerful than maven in many respects, but maven excels in dependency management and ease of deployment. So if you need the power of ant inside maven, use the maven antrun plugin:

Taken from
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html :

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase> <!-- a lifecycle phase --> </phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>

            <!--
              Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
              you can add between <target> and </target> in a
              build.xml.
            -->

          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Sean